# How do you recover from breaking a build on a branch

Tags: git, github, workflow, branch, git-branch

I'm having trouble finding the answer because I don't know what exactly to search. Say I'm working on a branch called dev. If I mess something up beyond repair and I want to go back to a working version, is this the correct sequence of actions?

Go back to master

Delete dev

Checkout a new branch from master and call it dev

Answer (score 1):

That will work. You can also just reset the `dev` branch with `git reset --hard master`